# Keyboard/Mouse working before install but not after install on Aspire V3-551 laptop

Tags: keyboard, acer, mousepad

I am trying to install Ubuntu 17.10 or 18.04 on an Acer Aspire V3-551 Laptop

When trying Ubuntu 17.10, 18.04 ( with Mint or Ubuntu Budgie) from booting the USB stick,m everything is working well...

If i install Ubuntu onto the HardDisk of the laptopt, sometime keyboard and mousePad works most of the time no, but after applying all suggested Uunbtu updates, it doesn' work anymore.

What is different in the version of Ubuntu I installed on the USB key and booting from, and the same one installed from that USB stick to the Hard Drive ?

Tks

JF
Found some old article on the web about plaing with GRUB configuration but it didn't worked

White picture is before updating Ubuntu ( Keyboard and mouse pad working) and the black picutre is after the Ubuntu Update ( keyboard / mousepad not functional anymore)

Note : the extra mouse and keyboard on the black picture have been connected after I saw the Laptop keyboard and mouse pad were not operational...

[image]

Comment: Seems driver issue. Run 'xinput list' command in the terminal and see the output.

Comment: I ran xinput before updating Ubuntu ( as the keyboard and mousepad were working well everything after the installation of Ubuntu.   And the ETPS/s Elantech Touchpad does not appear on the xinput List after I ran the initial Ubuntu Update... ( sorry I took a picture so I can't add it here).. Before the initual Ubuntu Update, 1st run, keyboard and touchpad were ok...

Answer (score 1):

Since your Elantech touchpad doesn't show up in `xinput list`, it seems there is some issue in the kernel parameters. Please follow me:

1. Check if you have a file named `crc_enabled` at `/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/`  if yes, check if its content shows `0x00`
2. If its `0x00` then change it to `1`
3. Now at `/etc/default/grub` alter the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line as `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"` and `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot

P.S. If there is no 'crc_enabled' file in the above directory, you can very well create one and take things forward as described.

Hope this will solve your matter. If not please check [this Arch Linux page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204564) for more detailed info.

Comment: Tks !!!!!  Seem to work   On linux Mint it is not there (crc_neabled) but ubuntu budgie yes,. so I'll go with Ubuntu budgie

Comment: I forgot to mention, if you don't have the "crc_enabled" file, you can create it with the content I mentioned and take things forward.

Comment: ok tks  @Arijit Chatterjee